# How can i get images from RSS feed in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, rss

```
       $ch = curl_init("http://runap.app.com/feed");
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
       $data = curl_exec($ch);
       curl_close($ch);
       $doc = new SimpleXmlElement($data, LIBXML_NOCDATA);
```

i am using above coding in my site for getting rss feed from http://runap.app.com/feed. for the above i am getting only recent posts title,description and categories.i can't get the post's images?...how can i get those images?..

Comment: That URI doesn't resolve, so we can't see the data. If the data doesn't include images, however, then you can't get them from it.

Comment: is there any possibilities to find where the query execute(fetching the RSS feeds) ?...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the images do not seem to be in the RSS feed, you should do it in two steps:

1. Load the RSS feed and extract all page links from it
2. Fetch each page link and extract the image URLs from there

Comment: Use an xpath on the your `$doc`ument's simplexml object to get the link URLs, and use curl again to fetch the page. Load it again with SimpleXml and xpath on `img@src`.

Answer (score 0):

Add following code at the bottom of your child theme’s functions.php file. It is recommended to customize this using a child theme.

```
function featuredtoRSS($content) {
    global $post;
    if (has_post_thumbnail($post - > ID)) {
        $content = ''.get_the_post_thumbnail($post - > ID, 'thumbnail', array('style' => 'float:left; margin:0 15px 15px 0;')).
        ''.$content;
    }
    return $content;
}

add_filter('the_excerpt_rss', 'featuredtoRSS');
add_filter('the_content_feed', 'featuredtoRSS');
```

Once you did that blog post images will be available in your RSS feed.